# Duplicity Restore Failure under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: backup, deja-dup

My Duplicity backup created under Ubuntu 16.04 cannot be restored under 18.04. The backup is on an external Linq hard disk. Is there any chance of recovering the backup hard disk? This the message that appears: [duplicity restore failure message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe8Zg.png)

FAILURE MESSAGE:

```
could not display contents of "backup": Error when getting information for
"file/media/Ubuntu/backup/duplicity-full******gz":input/output error
```

Ran duplicity in terminal as follows:

```
duplicity list-current-files file:///media/martin/Ubuntu/backup
duplicity list-current-files file:///media/martin/Ubuntu/backup
Synchronising remote metadata to local cache...
Copying duplicity-full-signatures.20180528T154702Z.sigtar.gz to local cache.
Attempt 1 failed. OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/media/martin/Ubuntu/backup/duplicity-full-signatures.20180528T154702Z.sigtar.gz'
Attempt 2 failed. OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/media/martin/Ubuntu/backup/duplicity-full-signatures.20180528T154702Z.sigtar.gz'
Attempt 3 failed. OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/media/martin/Ubuntu/backup/duplicity-full-signatures.20180528T154702Z.sigtar.gz'
Attempt 4 failed. OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/media/martin/Ubuntu/backup/duplicity-full-signatures.20180528T154702Z.sigtar.gz'
Giving up after 5 attempts. OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/media/martin/Ubuntu/backup/duplicity-full-signatures.20180528T154702Z.sigtar.gz'
```

Shows `OSError: [Errno 5]` can this error be overcome?

Furthermore full-signatures.20180528T154702Z.sigtar.gz is obsolete and in the backup there is a full backup dated 201808 which is the only one I need to recover

Comment: If the backup that is failing is one you don't care about, delete those files from the archive and try again.  I might make a copy of them somewhere else or just rename them out of an excess of caution though.

Answer (score 0):

I/O errors are usually bad news. What's the health of your device?

Example:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/yourdevice
```

If "smartctl" does not work, you may need this:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```